# Why we need Bower along with Nuget?

Tags: .net, bower, nuget-package

Why do we need another package manager when we use a Package manager like Nuget already?

Does Bower replace Nuget?

Comment: Interesting article here: http://simplyaprogrammer.com/2014/06/why-bower-is-better-than-nuget.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is Bower replaces Nuget?

**No**

[NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/) is package manager for the Microsoft development platform, distributed as a Visual Studio extension. It supports .NET Framework packages and native packages written in C++.

[Bower](https://bower.io/) is

> A package manager for the web.

It can manage components containing HTML, CSS or JavaScript files.
It is distributed as **npm** package (and npm is Node.js package manager).